# PHP: How to insert a single quote in front of <td>'.$var["something"].'</td>?

Tags: php

PHP-Beginner here looking for help, who's been trying for a full hour now to get this working.

I have a PHP line like this:

```
<td>'.$row["temperature"].'</td>
```

And I need to add a single quote `'` to the front.
So, if `$row["temperature"]` is e.g. `9.77` the result is `'9.77`

I've tried to escape the single quote with a backslash, tried using double-quotes, etc. but I just can't get it working.

Can someone tell me how to get this working?

Examples which didn't work:

```
<td>'\'.$row["temperature"].'</td>
<td>"\'.$row["temperature"]."</td> //this gives me  everything including the double quotes
<td>"\'.$row['temperature']."</td>
and many (failures) more...
```

Comment: `<td>'\''.$row["temperature"].'</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your first example is part of a longer expression like this:

```
echo 'Some more HTML markup <td>'.$row["temperature"].'</td> More Markup here too';
```

Then you're putting the leading `'` in the wrong place. Include it in the preceding string:

```
$row = ['temperature'=>3];
echo 'Some more HTML markup <td>\''.$row["temperature"].'</td> More Markup here too';
//                              ^^ insert here
```

Output:

> Some more HTML markup <td>'3</td> More Markup here too

See https://3v4l.org/o82U9